# Fast finding pixel position with current color interval

Tags: python, image, opencv, pygame, python-imaging-library

I stacked with problem of finding pixel position with current color interval.
This is very slow:

```
def inRange(self, tgColor, excColor, jump):
    if tgColor[0] > excColor[0] - jump and tgColor[0] < excColor[0] + jump and tgColor[1] > excColor[1] - jump and tgColor[1] < excColor[1] + jump and tgColor[2] > excColor[2] - jump and tgColor[2] < excColor[2] + jump:
           return True
    return False

 for iy in xrange(self.pilImage.size[1]):
        for ix in xrange(self.pilImage.size[0]):
            if self.inRange(data[ix, iy], self.targetColor, self.jump):
```

So, can you help me to improve this code, to make it work faster. (Image size - 640 x 480)
Maybe another lib: OpenCV, pygame, PIL?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be super-slow

OpenCV comes with a function [**cv2.inRange()**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.inrange#cv2.inRange). You pass the minimum and maximum pixel values and you get a binary image with passed pixels as white and failed pixels as black.

Then you can use [**numpy.where()**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the indices of pixels who are white.

Below is an example with grayscale values. It can be extended to color images also. [[Link]](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#converting-colorspaces)

Example:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randint(1,10, (5,5))
>>> x
array([[9, 5, 1, 3, 1],
       [7, 7, 2, 1, 7],
       [9, 1, 4, 7, 4],
       [3, 6, 6, 7, 2],
       [3, 4, 2, 3, 1]])
>>> y = cv2.inRange(x,4,8)
>>> y
array([[  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)

>>> z = np.transpose(np.where(y>0))
>>> z
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 1]])
```

Comment: Yep, my code is Very slow, cause it must to do 307200 iterations in cycle :(, but your advice is very useful. Thank you.